# TestNG tests not running in parallel

Tags: testng

I am frustrated with this issue. I have 3 nodes running with multiple browsers and grid starts nicely. Then I have a test suite that has 3 tests in it with multiple tests in each test. When I execute the tests, three browsers get occupied but after some time only one browser in first node stays occupied and the other two nodes just stay idle. Here is my setup code

```
public void setUpEagle() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);          
        ffdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);

        eagleLogin = new EagleLogin();
        LaunchEagle launchEagle = new LaunchEagle();
        driver = launchEagle.setUp(eagleLogin, LP1_GeneralManager, NonProductionPassword);

        // Print the Class Name
        System.out.println("Test Starting: " + this.getClass().getName());

        menuItem = new MenuItems();
        menu = new Menu();

        verify = new Verify();
    }

//testng.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="MRS_TestNGSuites1" verbose="10" parallel="tests" thread-count="30">    

<test name="mrs_testsuite1" junit="true">
    <classes> 
        <class    name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountAssignmentTestNI"/>                   
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountCommentPODDataVerifyTest"/>
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountDebtorPODAddressDataVerifyTest"/>
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountDebtorPODEmailDataVerifyTest"/>
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountDebtorPODPhoneDataVerifyTest"/>
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountDebtorPODPInfoDataVerifyTest"/>              
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountDebtorTearOffTest"/>
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountFinancialPODDataVerifyTest"/>
    </classes>
 </test>

 <test name="mrs_testsuite2" junit="true"> 
    <classes> 

        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountHeaderViewTest"/>
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.test.accounts.AccountID_CTC_US5211Test"></class>                                       
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountNotelineDataVerifyTest"/>                                    
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountNotelineTearOffTest"/>       
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.test.accounts.Account_ReOpen_And_CancelTimTest"/>          
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.PerformanceLegalAccountSearchTest"/>                                    
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AdvDebtorsLifecycleCancelledTest"/>                     
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AdvSearchAcctNumberTest"/>  
    </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="mrs_testsuite3" junit="true"> 
    <classes>                       
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AdvSearchLifecycleCancelledTest" />                 
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AdvSearchMultipleCriteriaTest" />                                       
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AdvSearchSaveCriteriaTest" />                                       
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountPODDataVerifyTest" />
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountPODMediDataVerifyTest" />                    
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountStatusPODDataVerifyTest" />                  
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.smoketests.noninvasive.AccountsTouchedReportTest" />
        <class name="com.squaretwo.eagle.test.accounts.AddPaymentPlanArrangement" /> 
    </classes>
 </test>
```

Comment: whats ur suite file like?

Comment: Here is my testng.xml. All my classes have the same setUpEagle()

Answer (score 0):

You have parallel=tests in your suite xml and only 3 tests in it (`<test>`). So you actually running no more than 3 browsers at a time. One of your `<test>`'s runs longer than other two thats why "after some time only one browser in first node stays occupied and the other two nodes just stay idle".